# Homotopy Type of Wedge Sum

Tags: algebraic-topology

I wish to show that the solid torus $\overline{B^2} \times S^1$ without a point of its interior is homotopy equivalent to $S^2 \vee S^1$.

1. Intuitively, these spaces are even homeomorphic - is this true?

My idea is that $\overline{B^2}$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$ without the point that we "remove" with the wedge sum, and the $S^1$ in the torus can be identified with the $S^1$ in the wedge sum.

2. If it is true, is it common to give an explicit formula for the homeomorphism between the two spaces?

Thank you already!

Remark: We have not covered Kampen's theorem yet.

Comment: These spaces aren’t homeomorphic because they don’t have the same dimension (more precisely: one contains an open subset homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, but no open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ can inject in $S^2$, or $S^1$ and the wedge product is covered by their reunion). Note that the point of $B^2$ which is removed is only removed for one particular value of the $S^1$-coordinate.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't even have an intuition for how one of the spaces could be deformed into the other. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Consider a circle going “all the way around” the solid torus going through the removed point, a small sphere enclosing said point, and glue them together. It shouldn’t be too hard to see that your solid torus minus a point can be deformed into this structure. Then deform the circle so that its extremities on the sphere are the same (or, instead, quotient the whole thing by a disk on the sphere containing said extremities – that should be a homotopy equivalence).

Comment: The given space is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$ with two points identified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I sketched the process as follows:

[image]